# JValue in Json4s (Scala): How to create an empty JValue

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I want to create an empty `JValue` to be able to parse JSON objects together.

As for now I am creating the `JValue` containing `{}` and then I am parsing the other objects to it and then in the end I remove the first row using an RDD, but I would like to create

```
var JValue: JValue = JValue.empty
```

from the beginning to be able to skip the removing part.

Is it possible to create an empty `JValue`?

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

var JValue: JValue = parse("{}")
val a = parse(""" {"name":"Scott", "age":33} """)
val b = parse(""" {"name":"Scott", "location":"London"} """)

JValue = JValue.++(a)
JValue = JValue.++(b)

val df = spark.read.json(Seq(compact(render(JValue ))) toDS())
val rdd = df.rdd.first()
val removeFirstRow = df.rdd.filter(row => row != rdd)
val newDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(removeFirstRow,df.schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you can start from an empty array like so:

```
var JValue: JValue = JArray(List.empty)
```

Calling the `++` method on the empty array will result in the items being added to that array, as defined [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/e014892cdd5231acf339c950d4e79a2d8cf4e452/ast/shared/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JValue.scala#L70-L80).

The final result is the following object:

```
[ {
  "name" : "Scott",
  "age" : 33
}, {
  "name" : "Scott",
  "location" : "London"
} ]
```

If you want to play around with the resulting code, you can have a look at [this worksheet on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/CwQpr0eOQWa4eoBPZMzdHg/12) (please bear in mind that I did not pull in the Spark dependency there and I'm not 100% sure that would work anyway in Scastie).

As you can notice in the code I linked above, you can also just to `a ++ b` to obtain the same result, so you don't have to necessarily start from the empty array.

As a further note, you may want to rename `JValue` to something different to avoid weird errors in which you cannot tell apart the variable and the `JValue` type. Usually in Scala types are capitalized and variables are not. But of course, try to work towards the existing practices of your codebase.

Comment: Consider marking the solution as accepted and perhaps upvote it as well if you have the rights to do so and you think it's useful for the community. :)